# How to use the "is" keyword with an object?

Tags: c#, as-keyword

How can I use the `is` keyword with an object, rather than an object's class?

Here is some code:

```
private bool IsObjectCompatableWithObjects(object obj, IEnumerable<object> objects)
{
    foreach (var item in objects)
    {
        if (obj is item)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The above code has the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'item' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you want to check the types or do you want to see if the object exists in the list?

Comment: Are you looking to know if object equals item or if your object is of the same type as item?

Comment: Change if condition as if (obj.GetType() == item.GetType())

Comment: Judging from the fuction name op is trying to check wheter an object's type fits the sequence of objects.

Comment: read about the `is` keyword [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to achieve something like this?

```
private bool IsObjectCompatibleWithObjects(object obj, IEnumerable<object> objects)
{
    return objects.Any(i => i.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()));
}
```

To test:

```
var objects = new object[] { 7, "foo", DateTime.Now, Guid.NewGuid() };

Console.WriteLine(IsObjectCompatibleWithObjects(1, objects));
Console.WriteLine(IsObjectCompatibleWithObjects("test", objects));
Console.WriteLine(IsObjectCompatibleWithObjects(3f, objects));
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

`is` is used against the `type` itself and NOT against the instance of type. So if you need to check if the item is of type object probably you should write -

```
if (item is Object)
```

instead of

```
 if (obj is item)
```

**But then everything is `object`**, so it is of little help. If you need to just check if the type if item in the list is same as type object, then you should do -

```
 if (item.GetType() == obj.GetType())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if your object is include in your enumerable of objects, you can use `Enumerable.Contains` from `System.Linq`:

> Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element by using the default equality comparer.

You can use it like this:

```
private static bool IsObjectCompatableWithObjects<T>(T obj, IEnumerable<T> objects)
{
    return objects.Contains(obj);
}
```

Basically, you are doing something like this:

```
private static bool IsObjectCompatableWithObjects<T>(T obj, IEnumerable<T> objects)
{
    foreach (var item in objects)
    {
        if (obj.Equals(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can look for the exact implementation [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,f60bab4c5e27a849).